# Using 'keys' in React to render an array of input box/ button

Tags: reactjs, react-native, arraylist

I have a table(array of objects) in React. I have a input box/ button for each row. Currently, I m using index in react local state (for input box/button).  But 'index' results in messed up table, when filtered. Read link https://www.menubar.io/react-keys-index/ and trying to use 'keys'. Can someone help  for accessing the array of input boxes and buttons using keys? My code is below:

```
 companies.map((company,index)=>{
 return (
 <tr key={company.id}>
   <td onClick={this.props.onClick.bind(this, company)}></td>       
   <td>{company.vacancy}</td>     
   <td key={company.id}>            
         <p><input type="text" value={this.state.company.messages[index] || ''} name={this.state.company.messages[index]} onChange={this.handleMessageChange.bind(this,company,index)}/></p>
         <p><button type="button" onClick={() => this.sendSMS(company,index)}>SMS</button></p>
  </td>                          
 </tr>
   );
  })
```

I have companyId as unique value.

Comment: Use `company.id` instead. For more info about the behavior you are getting, read the linked post below.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding unique keys for array children in React.js](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43892905/2030321)

Comment: @Chris Yes but I m not sure how to access/ use 'keys' in an array of input boxes? Any link or example ?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys-must-only-be-unique-among-siblings

Comment: @Chris Thanks for the links! Can you help in using  'key' instead of 'index' in input box and button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use arrays to store the values of items that can rearrange because then you would also have to rearrange the array in order to maintain the correct item-to-value relation.

Use an object instead:

```
<input 
  type="text"
  value={this.state.company.messages[company.id] || ''}
  name={this.state.company.messages[company.id]}
  onChange={this.handleMessageChange.bind(this, company)}
/>
```

Your state in the constructor would then look something like:

```
this.state = {
  company: {
    messages: {}
  }
};
```

This way, your messages per company are stored as:

```
company: {
 messages: {
   someCompanyId: "blah blah",
   anotherCompanyId: "blah",
   ...
 }
}
```

This makes the storing of the values independent of index and order.

Answer (score 2):

Since companyId is unique,it can be used as key.

In your example key should be used in tr and not in the inner td

`<tr key={company.id}>` - correct usage 
`<td key={company.id}>` - Incorrect usage

Keys only make sense in the context of the surrounding array.

You can refer the  ***Extracting Components with Keys*** in https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html which Incorrect and correct Key Usage

You can refer  [Understanding unique keys for array children in React.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28329382/understanding-unique-keys-for-array-children-in-react-js/43892905#43892905) for any operations in the array (filter in your case).

Comment: This is correct, but doesn't answer OP's issue. Take a look in the comments.